# Mailgun blocking my IP?

Tags: smtp, mailgun

Trying to set up mailgun through [nullmailer](http://untroubled.org/nullmailer/) for email delivery from a box (let's call it `a.example.com`).

After some experimenting I found out that this works well for my `/etc/nullmailer/remotes`:

```
smtp.mailgun.org smtp --port=587 --user=postmaster@mg.example.com --pass=PASSWORD
```

But this only works on `b.example.com`, not on `a.example.com` that I wanted to set this up on.  Looking further into this it looks as if mailgun is blocking my server.

On my laptop and b.example.com this works:

```
$ telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587
Trying 52.38.21.43...
Connected to smtp.mailgun.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ak47 ESMTP ready
```

But on a.example.com it stops:

```
$ telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587
Trying 52.38.21.43...
```

Now I wonder if Mailgun is blocking a.example.com? And if so, if this is only temporary. And if not, what *is* going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Scaleway.com (where `a.example.com` is) decided to block outgoing SMTP traffic *by default*.